# "[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run" message

Tags: testing, testng, testng-eclipse

Last week I was running this script and it was running fine.

[image: ![enter image description here]

After a week when I again ran it, it throws **`[TestNG] No tests found`**.

Nothing was run as in the picture below

[image]

So why is this happening? Any Solution for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have to degrade TestNG version to 6.10, after that it is running.